# MailMessage.Subject Finnish encoding

Tags: c#, encoding, mailmessage

I'm trying to send a Finnish email with "Käyttörajan muutos" in subject.

Tried different encodings:

```
message.Subject = "=?iso-8859-1?B?" + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(strSubject)) + "?=";
```

and

```
message.Subject = "=?utf-8?B?" + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strSubject)) + "?=";
```

As a result I get:

```
K&#228;ytt&#246;rajan muutos
```

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: It is encoded in 1252, just like you asked for.  Whatever program or software you use to receive and display the message is unhappy about it.  Consider using the MailMessage.SubjectEncoding property instead.

Comment: I've tried it. Result was the same.

Answer (score -1):

The main problem was, when I was implementing subject from Request, I was using

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Request.Form["strSubject"]);
```

And this already encoded my string to `"K&#228;ytt&#246;rajan muutos"`.

So,

```
message.Subject = "=?utf-8?B?" + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strSubject)) + "?=";
```

works.